# Computing a sum manually

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, estimation

I came across a sum  I needed to compute for a question but I wasn't able to evaluate it manually ( I ended up using Wolfram ).

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [1000(2+0.5n)e^{-0.4n}]
\end{equation}

I was curious however if there was a technique to evaluate or approximate the value of the sum (such that I didn't need a computer to do it for me). Any help would be greatly appreciated! (Note: The sum evaluated to 9150.15)

Comment: I suppose that you are aware of the fact that that sum is equal to$$2000\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-0.4n}+500\sum_{n=0}^\infty ne^{-0.4n}.$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes for sure, I just don’t know what to do with the e’s. Power series came to mind but I’ve never seen them being summed like this

Comment: Aren't you aware of the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac 1{1-x}$ when $|x|<1$?

Comment: Ohhhh I see. That -0.4 goes into the E giving a smaller common ratio. This makes sense.

Comment: For the second sum if you let $x=e^{-0.4}$ then you can express the sum in terms of the derivative of a geometric series.

Comment: @JudeCarter Yes this is now something I’ve seen. Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: You may also use $\sum_{n=1}^N nf(n) = \sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{n=k}^N f(n)$, which can be proved in a similar way to how you change the order of integration for iterated integrals